# HTML - Apply CSS - with parent Div with id to child div with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to apply CSS for parent div with ID to child div with CSS.

Need to apply

`ui-selectlistbox-listcontainer` class div `height` as 100% with parent div `id="tableForm:mainTable:selectFilterMenu-crop"`.
 And this code child div is dynamically created. So need to apply `height` = 100% thow CSS only.

Please suggest me to apply css for child div height as 100%,

HTML:

```
<div id="tableForm:mainTable:selectFilterMenu-crop" class="ui-selectmanymenu ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width:165px; height:270px">
<div class="ui-selectlistbox-listcontainer" heigth="200px">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS: // Not working

```
#tableForm:mainTable:selectFilterMenu-crop div.ui-selectlistbox-listcontainer {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: you need to wrap your css with <style></style> tags

Comment: Your id disobeys the w3c specification. You should fix it first. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: And divs do not have the `height` attribute, and if they did, you'd have to spell it correctly.

Comment: @obfish You are linking to an older version of the standard. `id` is allowed to have any value, as long as it is unique, is not the empty string, and does not contain space characters. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#changed-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `:`

```css
#tableForm\:mainTable\:selectFilterMenu-crop {
  border:2px solid;
}

#tableForm\:mainTable\:selectFilterMenu-crop div.ui-selectlistbox-listcontainer {
    height: 100% !important;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableForm:mainTable:selectFilterMenu-crop" class="ui-selectmanymenu ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width:165px; height:270px">
<div class="ui-selectlistbox-listcontainer" >
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser will tries to read the part after : as pseudo-element. For example, if you have an id `my-id` and you want to address the `before` pseudo-element, you'll write

```
#my-id:before
```

Try to replace `:` with `-`

```css
#tableForm-mainTable-selectFilterMenu-crop div.ui-selectlistbox-listcontainer {
  height: 100% !important;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableForm-mainTable-selectFilterMenu-crop" class="ui-selectmanymenu ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width:165px; height:270px">
  <div class="ui-selectlistbox-listcontainer" heigth="200px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer gets downvoted, because it correctly explains the source of the problem, and it provides a solution that works.